# Plot Computed Variables from ROS Subscriber

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, I am trying to plot data that I obtained from ROS Subscriber.
I have tried using this code from [question](https://answers.ros.org/question/264767/plotting-real-time-data/)

So I modified my code to be as follows:

```
def PlotVariable(self, msg):
        global counter

        if counter % 10 == 0:
            stamp = msg.header.stamp
            time = stamp.secs + stamp.nsecs * 1e-9
            plt.plot(time, self.linear_velocity[0], '-')
            plt.axis("equal")
            plt.draw()
            plt.pause(0.00000000001)

    

# If execution is needed will run after this line
if __name__ == "__main__":
    counter = 0   
    # This call initialises the class
    receiveData = OptitrackReceive()

    rate = rospy.Rate(10)
    
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():

        obsArray = np.hstack(
        [receiveData.rotMatrix.reshape(-1),
        receiveData.position,
        receiveData.linear_velocity,
        receiveData.angular_velocity])
    
        # rospy.loginfo("Velocity: \r\n" + str(receiveData.velocity))
        rospy.loginfo("Position: \r\n" + str(receiveData.pos_converted.pose.position))
        rospy.loginfo("Orientation: \r\n" + str(receiveData.eulerAngle))
        rospy.loginfo("Rotational Matrix \r\n" + str(receiveData.rotMatrix))
        rospy.loginfo("Rotational Matrix from Quat: \r\n" + str(receiveData.rotMatrixComp))
        rospy.loginfo("Linear Velocity: \r\n" + str(receiveData.linear_velocity))
        rospy.loginfo("Angular Velocity: \r\n" + str(receiveData.angular_velocity))
        rospy.loginfo("Observation Array: \r\n" + str(obsArray))
                
        rate.sleep()
        
        counter += 1
  
        plt.ion()
        plt.show()
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ted/catkin_ws/src/transmit_thrust/scripts/OptitrackReceiveV3.py", line 201, in <module>
    plt.show()
  File "/home/ted/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 254, in show
    return _show(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/ted/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 3248, in show
    manager.canvas.figure.show()
  File "/home/ted/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 437, in show
    manager.show()
  File "/home/ted/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 570, in show
    self._shown = True
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "/home/ted/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 28, in _restore_foreground_window_at_end
    yield
  File "/home/ted/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_tk.py", line 568, in show
    self.canvas.manager.window.attributes('-topmost', 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1636, in wm_attributes
    return self.tk.call(args)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 621, in after_cancel
    data = self.tk.call('after', 'info', id)
RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop
```

A solution to this problem or other solutions to plotting in real time would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/335558/plot-computed-variables-from-ros-subscriber/) by [haloted](https://answers.ros.org/users/46111/haloted/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2019-10-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved my own problem using rqt_plot. By publishing velocity information in a geometry_twist message to a specific set topic and call the rqt_plot to visualise it.

---

Originally posted by [haloted](https://answers.ros.org/users/46111/haloted/) with karma: 32 on 2019-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0